# regex to match number comma number

Tags: javascript, regex, web

This is what I have right now:

```
^[0-9]([,][0-9])?$
```

My problem is that i want to be able add more than one digit before and after my comma.

examples:

```
1,12
12,12
123,12
12,123
```

All above numbers are supposed to be valid.

Comment: Do you want the `,123` suffix to be optional?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
/^\d+,\d+$/
```

The `+` 'matches the preceding item one or more times.'

References:

- [JavaScriptRegular Expressions,at Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 4):

Use `+` sign, and also remove `[]` brackets around `,`(they are not neccessary):

```
^[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)?$
  //  ^-------^---------here they are
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two regex main repeaters, the first is `*`, that say "repeat zero or more times". The second is `+` that say "repeat one or more time".

In this case, you need repeat one or more times the integer value and the decimal value. So you can try it:

```
  ^[0-9]+([,][0-9]+)?$
```

So it will validate:

```
  0
  0123
  1,12
  1,0
  1,12340
```

But not will validate:

```
  1,
  ,0
  -1,0
  1e-10
```

Tips:

- You can replace `[0-9]` with only `\d`. It mean the same thing;
- You don't need group *comma*, just use `,` instead of `[,]`. You use that only for more than one possibilities, like accept comma and dot: `[,\.]`;

Following the tips, you can try:

```
  ^\d+(,\d+)?$
```