# Regex to Match (number-number) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I detect strings in Javascript that end with (number-number) at end of string?

Examples of strings I'm looking to match:

```
High (0-22)

Low (23-100)
```

Comment: what do you try so far?

Comment: nothing. I don't even know where to start

Comment: You could start with google.com searching for some regex article

Comment: What is a "number"? Non-negative integer? Integer? Decimal?

Comment: you can learn pretty much anything on Google - this is true.. I wouldn't post the question if I found the answer on Google though. IM SICK OF GETTING MY POSTS DOWNVOTED... AND WHEN I TALK ABOUT GETTING HACKED OVER BLUETOOTH THEY DELETE MY POSTS IMMEDIATELY

Comment: start talking about the Illuminati and see how quickly you get busted

Comment: @user2476265 if you're sick of getting your posts downvoted then read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: People like to see some level of effort at solving the problem yourself before you ask for help. Look at my answer, try to learn something and then work on fixing it yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regex to match number comma number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615396/regex-to-match-number-comma-number)

Comment: Don't take it personally: people downvote your content, not you. And of course if you talked about the illuminate, that should be downvoted. This is a programming site, after all.

Comment: @JustinPowell you shouldn't answer bad questions. You only promote the practice. I do agree with your other points, though.

Comment: People... if you downvoted this without knowing that it was a duplicate... I implore you to also downvote the other post! ...let's let stackexchange know what acceptable content looks like!

Comment: @user2476265 your question and the one that I linked as the basis of your duplicate are **vastly** different. In the linked question, user1546193 actually **tried** something in regex before asking for help. You didn't try anything at all. You just saw a problem and instead of googling or reading on regular expressions you just gave up. **Your post** is unacceptable content because you were so lackadaisical as to not try anything before seeking help. You just asked for solution without learning.

Comment: You guys are ruining Stackoverflow to make a point about people posting on here because they're "lackadaisical"? And you guys even have the nerve to downvote people who answered! That's CRAY! You guys need to question whether or not YOU are the ones typing or there is some malevolent force behind you controlling your every whim. Illuminati - Hi.

Comment: @user2476265 looking through your post history, you should probably see a psychiatrist since you see to have some sort of paranoia disorder. The "illuminati" is not controlling me. I just simply don't like ignorant question and, even more so, ignorant people such as yourself. Additionally, the people who answered should *not* have answered in the first place since it only promotes further the misbehaviour you have exhibited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Regex

```
/.*\(\d+-\d+\)$/
```

---

### Explanation

`.` = any character

`*` = zero or more times

`\(`,`\)` = literal parentheses (must escape with backslash or it will be interpreted as a regex control character)

`\d` = digit

`+` = one or more times

`-` = literal hyphen

`$` = end of line

---

### Links

- [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/6L478ot1/) is a jsfiddle to play with.
- http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has lots of useful information.